# How to get IE7 to change name attribute of radio buttons using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, clone, fieldset

I'm using plain vanilla JavaScript to clone fieldsets and change the ID/name attributes of any of the form fields within the fieldset.

Everything works properly, except in IE7 the cloned radio buttons are all treated as one group. For example, in one fieldset, I have two radio buttons. When I clone it and add another fieldset, then click in the last radio button of the new fieldset, it unchecks the very first radio button.

This appears to be a bug in IE7 where it doesn't change the name attribute (even though everything is working properly in other browsers). I'm using input.getAttribute("name") and have also tried input.htmlName, but neither makes a difference.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get IE7 to treat radio button group for each fieldset as a separate group?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
input.setAttribute("name", inputName + fieldsetNumber);
```

Regular text INPUTs work fine, the issue just involves IE7 and radio buttons. From everything I've dug up, there's a bug in IE7 with radio buttons.

Comment: Can you post your existing script? I'd have thought that `input.name = "newName";` would work to set the `name` attribute to the `"newName"` string..?

Comment: I've updated my post above with an example. I've also tried input.name, like you posted in your comment, but that didn't work either. Stupid IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the solution posted here: http://code.rawlinson.us/2006/03/another-ie-gotcha-dynamiclly-created.html to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works, tested.

```
function changeName(targetId,newName){
 document.getElementById(targetId).name = newName;
}
```

Comment: Tested on what browser/platform?

Comment: I'm changing the attributes that are within the cloned object. Changing the IDs/names works fine in IE7 for text inputs, but it doesn't in radio buttons.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Ah, good point. This was not tested with IE7 as OP requested. I will look into editing or removal.

Comment: @Zoolander - You can still assign unique id's to your cloned objects.

Comment: @Travis J - Yeah, but each radio group needs to have a separate name. Currently, all radios on the page that are dynamically are treated as though it's one group (as opposed to separate fieldsets). According to MS' site, changing the name via JS will not change it in the programming model, but the change is reflected in the submitted elements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534184.aspx DUMB!

Comment: @Zoolander - Interesting. Perhaps if you completely strip the element from the DOM and replace it with a new one that has the new name.

Comment: @TraviJ - I think that's the only way. Just going to be a lot of work as the fieldsets contain a lot of HTML. Ugh. I hate IE.