# Create input type=radio with pure Javascript and retrieve them by name (ie7 standards on ie9)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This script works on IE9:

```
var newAnswer = document.createElement("input");
newAnswer.setAttribute("type","radio");
newAnswer.setAttribute("id","1");
newAnswer.setAttribute("name","answers");
```

And generate this html:

```
<input name="answers" id="1" type="radio" value="1"/>
```

And I can create several input type=radio and retrieve them by name.

But **if I set the document mode to ie7 standard** each generated input looks like:

```
<input submitName="answers" id="1" type="radio" value="1"/>
```

**(notice the name attribute appears as submitName)**

And then I can't use something like:

```
var answers = document.getElementByName("answers");
```

Then the getElementsByName doesnt' work and also why is IE (document mode ie7 standard) creating this attribute "submitName" ? is this the expected behavior ? Can I make the code works in document mode ie7 as it works on ie9 mode ?

I've read a couple of answers question but I can't get it.

Comment: Try this: `newAnswer.setAttribute("name", "answer", 0);`

Comment: @cookiemonster what's the third parameter for? :O Never saw it before.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: I hadn't either. Just came across this [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It seems to set how case sensitivity is handled in IE. Not sure if it's a fix for this issue though.

Comment: "If two or more attributes have the same name, differing only in case, and lFlags is set to 0, this method assigns values only to the first attribute created with this name. All other attributes of the same name are ignored." Basically casing also plays a role in duplicate attribute detection. Disable casing and it also doesn't check if an attribute exists already. I think something else that can be taken from this is that IE is attempting to set a "name" attribute already without actually using it.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9386973/3096782) points to a blog that shows a technique to get around this.

Comment: See [name attribute | name property (Internet Explorer) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534184.aspx) for info. I also found [this post](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/internet-explorer-7-and-dynamically-created-form-inputs/).

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for taking you back to the dark-ie-era but I'm on my way to js and just tried this (error, can't continue until have it solved) i will take a look to the links you have provided.

Comment: It’s an age-old not-really-a-secret that in older IE the `type` of an input element can not be changed dynamically – and just using `document.createElement("input")` sets it to the default type `text` while doing so. Using the complete HTML code of the tag in createElement is the only way around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay starting over from the last one, this one I just tested and it is working in IE7

```
var testName = null;
function createElementWithName (type, attrs) {
    if(testName ===null) {
        try{
            var x = document.createElement("<input />");
            testName = false;
        } catch(e) {
            testName = true;
        }
    }
    var htmlStr = testName || !attrs.name ? type : '<' + type + ' name="' + attrs.name + '">';
    var elem = document.createElement(htmlStr);    
    for (var prop in attrs) {
         elem.setAttribute(prop, attrs[prop]);   
    }    
    return elem;
}


var attrs = { type: "radio", name: "answers" };

attrs.id="foo1";
var newAnswer1 = createElementWithName("input", attrs);

attrs.id="foo2";
var newAnswer2 = createElementWithName("input", attrs);

attrs.id="foo3";
var newAnswer3 = createElementWithName("input", attrs);

document.getElementById("xxx").appendChild(newAnswer1);
document.getElementById("xxx").appendChild(newAnswer2);
document.getElementById("xxx").appendChild(newAnswer3);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfC5r/1/show/